# How to access WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 Endpoint in BPS 3.1.0

Tags: bpel, wso2, apache-ode, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 BPS Server,i written proxy service in Wso2 ESB 4.8.0,How can i access this endpoint into BPS  server. How to write the business logic to it.

I saw many BPS server examples and they are developing in Eclipse from using Carbon Application project.

@How can i  access WSO2 ESB Proxy service Endpoint into Bps Server and how can i write the logic to this.

Some one guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your requirement; do some business logic from WSO2 BPS and pass the output from BPS to your created proxy service in WSO2 ESB. Yes,this is possible to implement with WSO2 BPS.

You can follow up the references in [1,2,3] as the starting point on how to write a simple business logic inside a bpel and invoke an external web service with the logic output.

Please note,it will be easy for you,if you can start developing bpels with WSO2 Dev Studio eclipse plugin[4] as it provides GUI support to create the  business process.

[1] http://wso2.com/library/articles/writing-simple-ws-bpel-process-wso2-bps-apache-ode/

[2] http://thiliniishaka.blogspot.com/2012/10/develop-ws-bpel-process-using-wso2.html

[3] http://thiliniishaka.blogspot.com/2012/10/part-2-developing-ws-bpel-process-using.html

[4] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/09/develop-wsbpel-apache-ode-wso2-developer-studio/

Thanks;

Comment: Thank you Sureshika,But while i am consuming my BPS server endpoint in WSO2 ESB(with help of payload factory and target endpoint) ..i am getting this error please help me.. **<faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is http://localhost:9763/services/AddingPL/ and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</faultstring>**